# Рандомизация файлов, но с сохранением изначальных имен и расположений

Tags: python, файлы

Помогите пожалуйста, я хочу написать программу, которая будет случайно перемешивать файлы в директории, но с сохранением изначальных имен файлов.
Моя задача - перемешать все звуки в игре. У меня есть папка со всеми звуками, но они так-же расположены в разных папках. Каким образом мне перемешать их, при этом сохранив структуру.
Как мне собственно подойти ко всему этому?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отсортировывать файлы в самой дирректории нет никакого смысла, это всего лишь визуальное представление, зависящее от конкретной системы.

Ваша игра использует путь к файлу и он не зависит от сортировки в папке, поэтому :

1. Для получения всех файлов/папок в директории в python можно использовать `os.listdir()`, при этом какой-либо порядок файлов не гарантирован и может быть абсолютно произвольным и также зависит от системы. Вы можете получить список файлов в директории, например так:

```py
files = []
for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        files.append(file_path)
```

Затем с помощью метода `shuffle()` из библиотеки `random` перемешать случайным образом пути к файлам в списке затем уже использовать их.

2. Возможно действительно нужно случайным образом переименовать файлы, примерно это можно сделать так:

```py
file_list = os.listdir(folder_path) # Список путей к файлам в указанной папке

new_file_list = random.shuffle(file_list) # Перемешанный список с путями

for i, file_path in enumerate(file_list):
    new_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, os.path.basename(new_file_list[i])) # Объединяем путь к папке и полученное имя файла, имя берем из перемешанного списка 
    os.rename(os.path.join(folder_path, file_path), new_file_path) # Переименовываем файл
```

Comment: Возможно я не так объяснил. У меня есть игра, и она воспроизводит звук под названием "1" при открытии двери, и звук "2" при закрытии. Моя задача поменять звуки местами. Звуков много, и я хочу полностью их перемешать.

Comment: тогда вариант 2 , звук 1 пересохранится под именем 2 , а звук 2 под именем 1, но если использовать random, то элементы списка могут и не перемешатся, если элемента два - вероятность 50% что они перемешаются поэтому можно использовать не random а просто перевернуть список с помощью reverse() либо использовать эти методы совместно, ну или задать новые пути вручную а потом уже сохранять.